# Can't fully uninstall Visual Studio 2019 - how do I clear the app list?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have uninstalled Visual Studio 2019 but it still exists in the App list in Windows 10. If I select it from that list and click *Modify* or *Uninstall* the VS installer opens as expected but displays the error shown in the screenshot, below.

For yucks I tried re-installing VS2019 and then uninstalling it but it had no effect and I had 2 VS2019 entries in the App list.

[image]

How do I clear this old install out? I would prefer to clean this up before installing VS2020...

Edit: I deleted the entries from the registry under `SOFTWARE/Microsoft/VisualStudio` but no change.

Comment: My first impulse, given this is Windows World, would be to reboot the machine and check the app list again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Microsoft Support Article for this issue:

[Uninstall Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Standard steps.   Then:

(Take care with the warnings)

> Remove all with InstallCleanup.exe  Warning
>
> Use the InstallCleanup tool only as a last resort if repair or
> uninstall fail. This tool might uninstall features from other Visual
> Studio installations or other products, which then might also need to
> be repaired or reinstalled.
>
> If you experience a catastrophic error and can't repair or uninstall
> Visual Studio, you can run the InstallCleanup.exe tool to remove
> installation files and product information for all installed instances
> of Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio 2019, or Visual Studio 2022.
>
> Here's how to run the InstallCleanup.exe tool:
>
> Close the Visual Studio Installer.
>
> Open an administrator command prompt. To open an administrator command
> prompt, follow these steps:
>
> Type cmd in the "Type here to search" box. Right-click Command Prompt,
> and then choose Run as administrator. Enter the full path of the
> InstallCleanup.exe tool and add the command-line switch you prefer. By
> default, the path of the tool is as follows. The double quotes enclose
> a command containing spaces:
>
> Note
>
> If you can't find InstallCleanup.exe under the Visual Studio Installer
> directory, which is always located at %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft
> Visual Studio, here's what to do next. Follow the instructions to
> install Visual Studio. Then, when the workload selection screen is
> displayed, close the window and follow the steps on this page again.
>
> Switch    Behavior
> -i [version]  Default if no other switch is passed. It removes only the main installation directory and product information. Use this switch
> if you intend to reinstall the same version of Visual Studio. If a
> [version] value is specified, only products with a version that start
> with this string value will be removed. For example, use the switch -i
> 17 with InstallCleanup.exe to remove all 17 versioned products.
> -f    Removes the main installation directory, product information, and most other features installed outside the installation directory, that
> might also be shared with other Visual Studio installations or other
> products. Use this switch if you intend to remove Visual Studio
> without reinstalling it later.

=======================

Additional notes that might possibly prove helpful.

.

Here is another article for uninstalling earlier versions of Visual Studio. I cannot vouch for it, but it is in a Microsoft forum.
.

Here is a Stack Overflow article on removing old versions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189199/how-to-uninstall-older-versions-of-visual-studio-safely

[Other link][2]

[2]: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/307198/is-there-any-universal-uninstaller-for-visual-stud.html#:~:text=For%20Visual%20Studio%202019%20(Professional,can%20uninstall%20it%20from%20Apps%20%26

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `InstallCleanup.exe`. Sadly, though it removed the legit version, it had no effect on the ghost in the installed app list...

Comment: However it DID make the "Shared components..." field under Install Locations in the VS2022 installer editable, which was my primary problem. Fixed that, but didn't answer the question ;-)

Comment: Strange about the Ghost component . Was there another version installed earlier?

Comment: I was incorrect in my comment above. InstallCleanup does not reliably make that field editable. Still stumped. Need to install VS2022 to a different drive and can't make it work, yet.

Comment: This Windows install is quite old and has had several versions, back to 2012 installed and removed several times. VS2022 works fine, but I can't change the install location. C: on this thing is packed.

Comment: I put in another article to assist

Comment: No love with the usual Add or Remove Programs process, following the link...

Comment: I tried to edit the link (unsuccessfully) . Start at https after [2] and copy it  - then the link works. Sorry about that. I did try

Comment: I put in a Stack Overflow article to remove old versions also.

Comment: “This Windows install is quite old and has had several versions” - The age of installation has no baring on this problem. At this point the key, that lists the program, is likely the only component that is actually installed.  This would definitely be the case if the uninstall tool, removed the second VS2019 install successfully. The SO question isn’t relevant for VS2017, VS2019, and VS2022.  Additionally, VS2019 and VS2022, can exist on the same system

Comment: [You can select a different location only when you first install Visual Studio. If you've already installed it and want to change the location, you must uninstall Visual Studio and then reinstall it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/change-installation-locations?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Yep, tried that several times. No luck.

Comment: You may be at a point where it would be faster and easier to reinstall Windows and then just install the version of VS you wish to use.